# SQL Server Database Encryption

Tags: security, encryption, database, sql-server, sql

Let's say two programmers are working on a website for a store. They've created a small database for an online store. Users would have to register and provide a username(e-mail address) password,home address, and have the option to store the credit card information on their account. Obviously, you don't want attackers to get any of this information. Assume one of the programmers was careless and didn't filter SQL statements and didn't take proper measures to ensure malicious code wouldn't be accepted. The programmer that is working on the database, what can he do it ensure that, even if an attacker was able to enter SQL statements into the form and gain access to the database, it would be encrypted? What type of encryption is this case, would work best?

According to this [SQL Server doesn't use salting when encrypting.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43/salting-when-encrypting)

What I'm looking for is, if a user entered the correct username/password he would gain access to his own account, but should an attacker use SQL injection, he would get an encrypted database that he must attack in order to get the information.

Note: The programmers are using SQL Sever 2012

Comment: You are looking to protect _all_ data? Or just the password hashes? Are you looking to protect the data such that even if the remote attacker had a copy of the source code and related configuration, they still wouldn't be able to access the data?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - Well, what I am looking for is, in SQL Server, how would you store user data, such that, if an attacker were to get a hold of the database, by SQL injection, he would get random strings and would have to decrypt it. It would be impossible, cause said hacker, doesn't have the key.

Comment: Storing Credit Card information is "can of worms" that you don't want to open. In regards to Database encryption you have to decide what attack vectors you are trying to protect from. This question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: @SaUce - I stated SQL injection as a possible attack.

Comment: Encrypting database does not protect against SQL injection.

Comment: @SaUce - I understand now, after a few clarifications. What I'm after is what encryption method can be used so that if an attacker uses SQL injections, gains access to the database, all the attacker gets is random strings that he has to decrypt using a key he doesn't have.

Comment: If attacker gets access to database but it is encrypted he will not be able to query it directly, if your application is prone to SQL injection attacker can always query database through your application and there is no encryption that will stop him.

Comment: @SaUce - I assumed it was a two step process if you will. The attacker could use SQL injection and get a hold of the database, provided the programmers used encryption, he wouldn't be able to see the user data. I guess my understanding of it was wrong. Thanks :D. So let me understand this, if your website is prone to SQL injection, encrypted or not, the attacker can gain access to the database and see user data. The only way to prevent SQL injection in the first place is the filter out statements and certain inputs.

Comment: IMO Your program would need to encrypt before writing to the DB, and decrypt after reading from the DB, you'd then have to have it encrypt with a different key per user.

Comment: @techie007-How can this be done? Do you have a link to a tutorial or page?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield yes your correct, Encryption is not a tool for stopping SQL injection. Database Encryption protect physical data at rest, application encryption protect data from being read outside of the application. If you use both methods your application still needs to be able to read data, therefore your application is the tool to bypass encryption and other security you have implemented.

Comment: @SaUce- The suggestion by techie007, would that work? Or if my site was attacked using SQL injection, the attacker would still be able to see the data?

Comment: What @techie007 recommends would prevent attacker from seeing data belonging to other users, only data of (hacked) user will be seen to attacker but if he found a way to break into 1 users account he will be able using SQL injection to determine other users and than log into each account and get their data. Bottom answer is NO. There are entire books that are written on Secure Coding.

Comment: @SaUce - As Frank Thomas suggested,"they store a (salted) hash of the password". Provided you use a salted hash, If you use SQL injection, the attacker would only get the hash correct? No way for acquiring the actual password?

Comment: unless the hashing algorithm has been 'broken' yes, it is theoretically impossible to reverse a hash to determine the original password, but advancements in hash cracking over the last decade have somewhat outstripped new algorithms, so advancements like GPU acceleration and Rainbow tables make a whole host of older algorithms unsuitable for security purposes.

Comment: @Frank Thomas,SaUce,techie007 Thanks for clarification. Hashing is a protective measure, just in case SQL injection was achieved, all the attacker has is a hash of the password, nothing they can use to break into an account. Correct?

Comment: @SaUce - Hashing is a protective measure, just in case SQL injection was achieved, all the attacker has is a hash of the password, nothing they can use to break into an account. Correct?

Comment: with SQL injection you don't need to know the password to log in to the account. One way hash would protect the data, but if you need to display in the application you will use 2 way hash and thus open the door for hacker to see it.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server encryption is for protecting data at rest, to protect backup files and prevent someone from accessing the database data files in a raw format.

it is NOT for protecting data from an app that has been written and configured to access that very data. keep in mind, attacks on your infrastructure proxied through one of your applications use that applications credentials and privileges to perform the attack. its like giving your housekey to your lowlife bother-in-law so he can dogsit, but expecting him not to be able to steal your TV. Even if you did your encryption at the app tier, the app has the keys to teh encryption, so any attackers do as well. the only real option is to tie the keys to the users, not the app itself, so that no user could ever decrypt cc data that was not their own.

Second, in order to legally store credit card data, you must meet industry PCI standards for security, which are well beyond the scope of this forum.

Everything about your question tells me that you should never ever ever let your coders store CC data. you guys are no where close to where you need to be to handle that data securely.

Edit: I note you have removed all references to credit cards from your OP, so if that is not your goal, disregard my comments on PCI standards. My comments on SQLServer encryption remain valid.

Comment: This is just hypothetical. I just wanted to understand what encryption method could be used for SQL Server in the way I described.

Comment: use a login system that allows you to store crypto certificates for each user. then at the application layer (not sql server) encrypt the sensitive data for that one user specifically before storing. that way, even if the app is compromised, the only the compromised users data that can be accessed, and the app becomes incapable of exposing all users data. if the application can access the data at all, it is vulnerable to sql injection. if you encrypt before you store though, an attacker would get gibberish.

Comment: How would a company, for example, Microsoft, store the username/passwords for e-mail accounts in an encrypted way? So, if an attacker tried SQL injection, all he would obtain is random strings that he would have decrypt using a key he doesn't have. So Assume Microsoft is using SQL Server 2012 for the database. Sorry ignore this. I was typing this as you  were making edits to your above post.

Comment: sites don't store passwords. they store a (salted) hash of the password, so that if it is ever stolen, the attacker can't use that info to login. this is one place where strong one-way hashing is better than two way encryption. What got adobe in trouble was that they encrypted their user account data instead of hashing the passwords, and over time, the ency algorithm they used became vulnerable (3des if you are interested). use SHA512 or an equivalent strenght hasher ( do not use SHA1 or MD5)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So where exactly are the passwords stored? "then at the application layer (not sql server) encrypt the sensitive data for that one user specifically before storing". Thanks for that. Is there a website or tutorial that shows how this could be done?

Comment: the passwords are not stored at all. you store the hash, and when someone logs in, their input password is hashed wth the same algorithm, which produces the same hash. if the hashes match, the user knows the password, and you don't have to store it at all. as for how to encrypt, it depends on your dev platform. here is an SO thread on how to encrypt a string using AES in c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net

Comment: I should point out that ASP.NET has a membership profile system that is good enough. It stores the password in a secure way.  You should not be saving credit card information yourself unless you know what you are doing.  I will go ahead it, the fact your even asking the question on how to store it, tells me you either allow somebody else to store that information for you.  Please be aware of the proper ways to handle credit card information, at no point should you be aware of credit card information, unless you are a payment processor.

Comment: that is correct, the ASPNET auth database uses salted hashing for storing passwords, and that is sufficient for user credentials. it doesn't do anything for other data about the user though; you have to cipher that yourself if you need to store other sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer ASP.Net membership provider's dbo.aspnet_Membership table.  It stores a user level password salt and encrypts the passwords before storing them.  Very similar to your requirement.

There is not out-of-the-box functionality available in SQL Server, unless you use the option to encrypt a column.  But then you are stuck with having to use the varbinary data type and also face a possible performance degradation (20% slower as per some articles).  Refer:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx